# loop to print out the even numbers from 2 to 100 in reverse order

Tags: java, loops

How would I do this? Sorry my first time posting here.

```
int controller = 100;
    while(controller <= 2)
    {
        System.out.println("Step 2");
        controller++;
    }
    System.out.println("Done");
```

Comment: you are almost there.Try to reduce the controller by 2 each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. You should reduce the index by 2 (not increment by 1), and you should check that the value is `>= 2` (not `<= 2`). Also, I believe you wanted to print `controller`. Like

```
int controller = 100;
while(controller >= 2)
{
    System.out.println(controller);
    controller -= 2;
}
System.out.println("Done");
```

or like

```
for (int controller = 100; controller >= 2; controller -= 2) {
    System.out.println(controller);
}
System.out.println("Done");
```

Comment: This prints out 11,9,7,5,3 why is that?

Comment: @TheRuke It can't be. This code is perfect. Check that your code matches up with this one

Comment: @TheRuke Please read your code more carefully. You're using `controller1` in the `while` loop to check if it is still greater or equal to `2`, but you're decrementing `controller`, a different variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a -2 decrement as already answered or a 'modulo 2' way.

```
for (int controller = 100; controller >= 2; controller --) {
   if (controller % 2 == 0)
      System.out.println(controller + " is even");
}
```